# Struts 2 get Json from DAO into the action class

Tags: java, jquery, sql, json, struts2

I have some unique probably understanding issue. I have jQuery Ajax call which call Struts2 action class which in turn calls DAO to get some data. However for some reason I do not get any data or any error, just a blank response when I add DAO operation in action class. Something is wrong and I need some eyes to tell me what is wrong,

This is my ajax call,

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "S2",
            //force to handle it as text
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data:{state_code:state_code },
            beforeSend: function (xhr, setting) {
                var url = setting.url;
                url = url.replace("&_=", "&t=");
                setting.url = url;
                },
            success: function (data) {              
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
```

This is my DAO Class,

```
public List<BnGetCitiesbyStateCodeBn> GetCitiesbyStateCode(String state_code) throws SQLException {
        List<BnGetCitiesbyStateCodeBn> cities = new LinkedList<>();
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();

            try {
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("select Distinct(city) from cities_extended WHERE state_code = '" + state_code + "'");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    BnGetCitiesbyStateCodeBn city = null;
                    city = new BnGetCitiesbyStateCodeBn();
                    city.setState_code(rs.getString("state_code"));
                    city.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
                    cities.add(city);
                    logger.info("Cities retreived are " + cities);
                    System.out.println(cities);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info("Error retreving Cities " + e);
            } finally {
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
        return cities;

    }
```

This is my Action class,

```
public class S2 extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5686197289029560661L;
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(S2.class);
    private String state_code;
    private String t;
    private List<BnGetCitiesbyStateCodeBn> cities;

    public S2() {
    }

    public void setState_code(String state_code) {
        this.state_code = state_code;
    }

    public String getT() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setT(String t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public List<BnGetCitiesbyStateCodeBn> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities(List<BnGetCitiesbyStateCodeBn> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public String getState_code() {
        logger.info("State code is " + state_code);
        return state_code;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        try {
            GetCitiesbyStateCode citydao = new GetCitiesbyStateCode();
            cities = citydao.GetCitiesbyStateCode(state_code);
            System.out.println(cities);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        logger.info("log4j2 works for Struts Method.Inside Execute Method of S2 Action Class");
         System.out.println("Inside action class");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

This is my struts xml,

```
 <package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">  
     <action name="S2" class="json.S2" method="execute">
            <result type="json"></result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

This is my bean,

```
public class BnGetCitiesbyStateCodeBn {
    private String city;
    private String state_code;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState_code() {
        return state_code;
    }

    public void setState_code(String state_code) {
        this.state_code = state_code;
    }
}
```

Whenever I comment out the calls to my DAO, I get json response back and everything works like log4j2 etc.,but when I uncomment that part,I get blank response.So I am guessing that probably my json config is missing something.

Appreciate if someone can take a look and let me know.

Ok I think I found the cause,

```
logger.info("state code in dao class is " + state_code);
                try {
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select Distinct city,state_code from cities_extended WHERE state_code = 'AL'");
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    logger.error("SQL Exception executing query" +ex);
                }
```

When I am passing `state_code` from ui, it gets messed up and when I hardcode the value like AL, it gives me the result perfectly fine. does underscore in parameter name does any harm ?

Comment: I do not see my earlier comments on this post by me and Andrea. Did someone deleted comments ?.

Comment: Are you sure that your dao returns not empty list?

Comment: Checking Aleksandr. Will let you know soon. Last time I checked it was working.But let me check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get SQL exception at the line

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select Distinct(city) from cities_extended WHERE state_code = '" + state_code + "'");
```

`distinct` is not a function, it's a statement, see a definition and example usage [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp). You need to modify the query

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select Distinct city from cities_extended WHERE state_code = '" + state_code + "'");
```

after this change everything should work like log4j2 etc.

Comment: Yes I did get SQL Exception. I am fixing it and trying again.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I think it was due to bad sql or parameter naming issue, just gave some update. Please see at the top of posting.

Comment: Eureka, Finally I got all my response in Json... bad query took almost a day's effort. Thanks Roman. Appreciate it.Next task is laying it out in jquery dialog now.

Comment: This is another error, but to have much fun you said  *I get json response back and everything works*. And error is in the `beforeSend` function, where you change the parameter names. Those names should be bound to the action class to populate parameter values. I'm not sure in the issue with parameter names bu they should follow JavaBeans conventions, and for readability and using Java code conventions be camel cased.

Comment: I do have that as well in action class state_code and t, if you look at query and dao class, there was one column for which I was not fetching results and adding it to the list. Fixed that as well. Sometimes going back and forth between myphp and netbeans creates a messy experience.:)

Comment: Please read my previous comment, and remove `contentType` option, that you don't use.

Comment: @KiranBadi He is right, why not to upvote and accept the answer that helped you?